# /dev/urandom to generate Random Number + ruby 2.3.0

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.2, ruby-2.3

Reading through the Ruby Doc [2.3.0](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/securerandom/rdoc/SecureRandom.html) which states the strategy that Ruby code uses to generate a Random Number.

- openssl
- /dev/urandom
- Win32

But looking [2.3.0](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_2_3/lib/securerandom.rb#L50-L80) Source I don't see any sign of `/dev/urandom` be used.

Atleast [2.2.2](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_2_2/lib/securerandom.rb#L135-L154) has `/dev/urandom` logic.

Please correct me if I'm wrong. I'm just helping myself understand how does random number are generated in Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

You have to look at the `Random.raw_seed` implementation which can be found in [`random.c`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_3_1/random.c#L625-L640).

And since the docs don't mention it: before trying to read from `/dev/urandom` the code tries to call [`getrandom(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrandom.2.html) on recent Linux versions (see [`fill_random_bytes()`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_3_1/random.c#L554-L560)).